# Whats the best way to remove print brackets from a python list?

Tags: python

The function below inserts a list into another list at a specified location.

What's the best way to remove the middle brackets from the output while leaving the outer brackets on?

```
def insert(list1, list2, index):

    pos = 0
    new_list = []

    if index > len(list1):
        index = len(list1)
    elif index < 0:
        index = 0

    for pos in range(0, index):
        new_list.append(list1[pos])

    #for pos in range(1):
    new_list.append(list2)

    while index != len(list1):
        new_list.append(list1[index])
        index += 1

    return new_list


list1 = ["b", "o", "o", "m"]
list2 = ["r", "e", "d"]
index = 2

new_list = insert(list1, list2, index)
print(new_list)
```

Output:

```
['b', 'o', ['r', 'e', 'd'], 'o', 'm']
```

Comment: I think you're using ``append`` in the middle instead of ``extend``.

Comment: Check out [Flattening a shallow list in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/406121/flattening-a-shallow-list-in-python)

Comment: not allowed to use `extend`

Comment: Note that `new_list.extend(lst)` is the same as `for item in lst: new_list.append(item)`.

Comment: Is there any particular reason that you're doing `list1 = ["b", "o", "o", "m"]` instead of `list1 = list("boom")` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use [list slicing](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html) to get the desired results:

```
list1 = ["b", "o", "o", "m"]
list2 = ["r", "e", "d"]
index = 2

print list1[:index]+list2+list1[index:]
>>> ['b', 'o', 'r', 'e', 'd', 'o', 'm']
```

To break it down, list slicing works as `lst[start:end]` So,

```
list1 = ["b", "o", "o", "m"]
index = 2
print list1[:index]
>>> ['b', 'o']

print list1[index:]
>>> ['o', 'm']
```

So now we divided the list into two parts and then we use `+` operator which concatenates the lists to join the first part, list2 and second part and get in result a final list.

If you want to encapsulate the things inside a function then:

```
def insert(list1, list2, index):
    return  list1[:index]+list2+list1[index:]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just substitute list.append() with [list.extend()](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/list_extend.htm).

```
def insert(list1, list2, index):

    pos = 0
    new_list = []

    if index > len(list1):
        index = len(list1)
    elif index < 0:
        index = 0

    for pos in range(0, index):
        new_list.extend(list1[pos])

    #for pos in range(1):
    new_list.extend(list2)

    while index != len(list1):
        new_list.extend(list1[index])
        index += 1

    return new_list


list1 = ["b", "o", "o", "m"]
list2 = ["r", "e", "d"]
index = 2

new_list = insert(list1, list2, index)
print(new_list)
```

Output:

```
['b', 'o', 'r', 'e', 'd', 'o', 'm']
```

Answer (score 0):

In your comment on the first post, you said you couldn't use extend(). Here's one way without needing it:

```
lists = ['b', 'o', ['r', 'e', 'd'], 'o', 'm']

new_list = []

for i in lists:
    if isinstance(i, list):
        for i2 in i:
            new_list.append(i2)
        continue

    new_list.append(i)

print(new_list)
```

Output:

```
$ python is.py 
['b', 'o', 'r', 'e', 'd', 'o', 'm']
```